# How to find the shortest line in a script

Tags: command-line, bash, files, scripts

I'm creating a script that prompts a user to enter a file name and search for the lines in the file, the longest line, and the shortest line. Here's what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a filename:"
read file
if [ -e "$file" ]
then
wc -l $file; echo "lines" && wc -L $file; echo "longest"
echo "$file exists"
else
echo "$file does not exist"
fi
```

This is the content of the text file I am using for the test. Hopefully this will help.

```
~$ cat simple.txt
I have too many things to do today.
It's going to take to long to get everything done.
My day is very busy.
Why such a long face.
```

Please excuse my formatting and or structure. I am at the early stages of learning shell script and appreciate any help.

Comment: I assume you'd like *all* indices of shortest/longest line(s) if multiple?

Comment: Also: do empty lines count (would be len `0`) please clarify.

Comment: Cool, but no answer(s) to my question(s).

Comment: The sample text I created has no empty lines so something should register with the script. I've posted the contents above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a bit of Python in your code, finding the length of the shortest line is easy:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; print(min(map(len, sys.stdin)))' < "$file"
```

`print` and `min` should be reasonably obvious. `map(len, sys.stdin)` applies the `len` (length) function to each entry in `sys.stdin`, which is each line in the standard input. Since this counts the newline in length of a line, your minimum length will be 1 more than what you'd expect. To fix that:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; print(min(map(len, sys.stdin.read().splitlines())))' < "$file"
```

Otherwise, a combination of `awk`, `sort`, and `head`:

```
awk '{print length}' "$file" | sort | head -1
```

`head -1` prints only the first entry, which, after sorting, would be the shortest line length. Or, entirely in bash:

```
{    
    IFS= read -r line
    min=${#line}
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        length=${#line}
        ((min > length)) && min=$length
    done
} < "$file"

echo "shortest line's length is $min"
```

Here, I used `{ }` to enclose the code section. This way, `< "$file"` applies to all of that section, so that both the first `read` and the `while` loop read from it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to exclude "\n" as a length.

Comment: @JacobVlijm no, but that's just a `-1` away.

Comment: In the test, all my files' shortest line is 1 :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm fixed using `stdin.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if empty lines are skipped? (OP should make clear)

Comment: No idea. If the shortest line is empty, well, it is the shortest line.

Comment: That's true, not clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your script there's:

```
wc -l $file; echo "lines" && wc -L $file; echo "longest"
```

You could change it with:

```
LENGTH=$(<"$file" wc -l)
LONGEST=$(while read thisline; do echo "$(<<<"$thisline" wc -L) $thisline";done <"$file"|grep -v '^0 '|sort -t" "|tail -1|awk '{print $1}')
echo "$LENGTH lines, $LONGEST longest"
```

That's it, with some fix to your script output.

The `while` create a new flux of data, containing the length of each line in the file. The `grep` exclude empty lines (that's 0 chars in length); there are no empty line in your case, but prevent is better than cure. Then `sort` put line lengths in ascending order, and `tail` get the last line, that's the highest number (the longest line length). `awk` is there to clean the output (that came out from the `wc`, <*length original_line*>) taking only the number at the beginning.

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Without using a script, using just AWK:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$0}{length($0)<length(x)&&x=$0;length($0)>length(y)&&y=$0}END{print "Shortest: "x"\nLongest: "y}' in
```

If you want it to prompt for a filename:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$0}{length($0)<length(x)&&x=$0;length($0)>length(y)&&y=$0}END{print "Shortest: "x"\nLongest: "y}' "$(read -p "Enter a filename:" x; printf "$x\n")"
```

Splitting it into two different commands:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$0}length($0)<length(x){x=$0}END{print x}' in # shortest line
awk 'length($0)>length(x){x=$0}END{print x}' in # longest line
```

If you want them to prompt for a filename:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$0}length($0)<length(x){x=$0}END{print x}' "$(read -p "Enter a filename:" x; printf "$x\n")" # shortest line
awk 'length($0)>length(x){x=$0}END{print x}' "$(read -p "Enter a filename:" x; printf "$x\n")" # longest line
```

```
$ cat in
I have too many things to do today.
It's going to take to long to get everything done.
My day is very busy.
Why such a long face.
$ awk 'NR==1{x=$0}{length($0)<length(x)&&x=$0;length($0)>length(y)&&y=$0}END{print "Shortest: "x"\nLongest: "y}' in
Shortest: My day is very busy.
Longest: It's going to take to long to get everything done.
$ awk 'NR==1{x=$0}{length($0)<length(x)&&x=$0;length($0)>length(y)&&y=$0}END{print "Shortest: "x"\nLongest: "y}' "$(read -p "Enter a filename:" x; printf "$x\n")"
Enter a filename:in
Shortest: My day is very busy.
Longest: It's going to take to long to get everything done.
```